# npm run build ELIFECYCLE error with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, web-deployment

I tried looking it up on older posts and I've tried the usual reinstall modules/clean npm cache. The code runs fine with npm start on localhost but whenever I try build/deploy the project I get the following:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~prebuild: portfolio@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: portfolio@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\JS_Learn\porfolio1\portfolio\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\JS_Learn\porfolio1\portfolio\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\belch\AppData\Roaming\npm;
9 verbose lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: CWD: F:\JS_Learn\porfolio1\portfolio
10 silly lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle portfolio@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: portfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid portfolio@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd F:\JS_Learn\porfolio1\portfolio
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error portfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json for reference, tried to delete it and reinstall every single dependecy manually aswell:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "homepage": "http://MyUserJustIgnore.github.io/portfoliov1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would please clarify what you mean by "...tried to delete it and reinstall every single dependecy manually"? Does that mean you run, for example, `npm install <package>` foe each package?

Comment: yes that what I meant. Just went through every single one of them with a npm i <pkg>

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Also have you tried to simply delete the entire `/node_modules` folder and just run `npm install` inorder for the packages to be installed from the `package.json` file?

Comment: Yeah I tried it aswell. :c

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. But ideally, if `npm start` runs fine then this does not seem to be a problem with the packages specifically. Which of these two is failling or it is both... `npm run build` or `npm run deploy`? We might need to look into your `npm` too:(

Comment: I'm currently using Github Pages for deployment so it runs npm run build in the predeploy script and there is where it fails for some reason.

Comment: Wait, I think I caught what's happening... did you run `npm install gh-pages  --save-dev`? You definitely need that package as part of your dependencies.

Comment: Yup it's right on the bottom of my package.json for devdependencies

Comment: Alright, so we can confirm that the project dependencies are all in place. Have you tried updating `npm` recently?

Comment: I double checked and it's the latest version (6.14.10)

Comment: Please check again because currently i'm running version `npm@7.6.3`, try upgrading to that too.

Comment: Still getting the same-ish error - node v15.11.0 / npm  v7.6.3 That's my final update before going to sleep. I can't figure out what's going on, I managed to get a ecommerce website up and running without any issues and now I'm struggling with a portfolio...

22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\belch\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)

Comment: Wait, is this a public repository [I think it should be public inorder for you to publish to github-pages]? If you don't mind, then please share a link and I have a more detailed look. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no worries, we're here to support each other. I'll check it out and share my findings too. Good night, but it's actually morning, in my part of the world:)

Comment: Ay man I figured out what happened I forgot to close a quotation mark on my public/index.html... I feel so dumb it's sad. I'll never forget to close a href tag again ever in my life. Ty for helping me out dude.

Comment: Oh, good to know that you were able to debug the issue. Yeah, those little things can mess you up. The worst part is that you never get a meaningful error so it's even harder to trace the issue. All the best.